# Need setup in vb.net, by keeping dll and exe in separate folder

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to create SETUP for vb.net window application. My application uses multiple dll 
so I want to keep dll in separate folder and exe in separate folder.

When I create setup, dll and exe are in same (Application Folder of setup), then it works, but when I create 2 different folder in Application Folder of setup, one for dll and one for exe, then it desn't work. Please suggest how can I ?

For Example:

Apllication / bin / 1.dll,2.dll ,3.dll and application exe.

when I create set up then all goes to applciaton folder. when i installed then all are installed in same folder.

but I need all dll goes to sperate and exe goes to sperate folder.

Thanks

Comment: multiple application using same dll and dont want to put that dll into GAC

Comment: It does take several years before programmers really understand what DLL Hell means.

Comment: Its not dll hell problem. Only want to keep dll in seprate folder and exes in seprate folder wile installed setup

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `AppDomain.Current.AssemblyResolve` event and load the assembly manually by calling `Assembly.Load`.

Make sure the add the event handler before JITting (calling) any methods or types that use the DLL.